# Alamofire request always fails with "The request timed out" if Socket.io is connected

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, socket.io, alamofire

if socket.io is connected Alamofire is not working as expected, always getting req time out error. Alamofire works if i disable Socket.io

this is the error i'm getting

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." 
UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60800044c720 
{Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" 
UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}},
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://enpoint.json, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://enpoint.json, 
_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}
```

and this

```
_tcp_connection_write_eof_block_invoke Write close callback received error: [89] Operation canceled
```

kind of similar issue reported on git https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1545 but no answers.

I don't know what i'm doing wrong! Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by changing alamofire parameter encoding. 
By default Alamofire sets encoding to `URLEncoding` if you are not passing any encoding argument.
Use `URLEncoding` for `GET` and `DELETE` request.
Use `JSONEncoding.default` for all other requests (API should have support for this).

Still i'm not sure why it was working w/o socket and wasn't working with socket on.